# MavensMate Project Update - How to determine you need to stop waiting for sync?

Tags: metadata, mavensmate, sublime, time

Ah, I didn't want to post here but I'm desperate for some kind of guidance. So..

I'm new to MavensMate as of this morning. Looking for a best practice or way to know that my Sublime 3 project update is no longer doing anything and I should scrap it and try again. Is there a way to see progress while performing an update?

To recreate my exact issue here are my steps

1. Open Sublime
2. From menu, MavensMate > Project> New Project (browser will open)
3. Enter project details
4. On Advanced tab, unselect everything except reports and dashboards
5. On Project Metadata tab, unselect all your standard folders except pages
6. Click create project

My browser has been hanging on "Updating Project" for a few hours now. Wondering if this is bc we have over 100K reports it's still getting metadata for or if there's some other reason. Can't tell if this is normal behavior, was unable to find documentation about the lag.

Any suggestions are helpful. Inb4 "use eclipse" - the reason I'm trying with Sublime is because of a heap space issue that configuration of .ini file did not solve. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with enabling tooling api? That might speed up little bit.

Comment: No, but it doesn't look like reports are a supported object? Not listed on page 21 under supported objects. https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf

Comment: To get around the heap space issue when I used eclipse, I installed the ant plugin. I was able to pull our entire org while still working in eclipse it worked really well but you did have to change some parameters to get it all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100K report is a big number. Even Eclipse hangs when doing such kind of operation.

One more consideration:

> Metadata API (used by eclipse and MavensMate) can deploy and retrieve up to 10,000 files or 400 MB at
>   one time. If either of these limits is exceeded, the deployment or
>   retrieval fails.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: yes, something happened to stop my connection. Instead of trying to grab all of the data I needed in one go (then not knowing if it was doing anything), I separated out my next tries. For my example, this meant going into my report folder and choosing only certain sub folders for each update. Wait times were certainly much shorter. :)